# how to save extra not required field in laravel default auth registration form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to customize the laravel auth registration. And I have added **father name** field in table and form. But father name field is not required. 
I added this field in registercontroller.php and in User model also.
And then, if submit the form with all fields then data inserts successfully, But if I submit the form without father name field (which is not required), then error comes: **f_name filed can not be null.**

If I remove f_name from fillable then f_name is not saving.

**Method in RegisterController.php is:**

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'f_name' => $data['f_name'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

**User.php is:**

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'f_name' , 'password',
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you did not make it nullable in the database.

The other thing is that you should not code like that. You should create a Request class (where you validate request) for users with `php artisan make:request UserRequest` in command line or terminal. See the following.

```
protected function create(UserRequest $userRequest)
{
   $user = new User($userRequest->all());
   $user->password => bcrypt($userRequest['password']);
   $user->save();

  // your rest of the code.

}
```

Comment: (2/2) QueryException
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'f_name' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `users`

Comment: is `present_employer` in the form?

Comment: Sorry please check once again

Comment: make `f_name` filed nullable in the database.

Comment: If I make this field null then working fine. But If I give it default value 0 then not working. Why?

Comment: it must be nullable.

Answer (score 1):

Case 1: You might have set field default value to not-NULL in DB. Check your migrations it shpuld be something like `$table->string('f_name')->nullable();` or Check in DB/phpmuadmin and set to NULL by default.

Case 2: Check your validator function, can set it to `sometimes`.

Comment: Error is: (2/2) QueryException
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'f_name' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `users`